# Wireless doesn't work only at home

Tags: wireless

For some reason, on 13.04, wireless doesn't work ONLY on my home network. This is only an issue with ubuntu. On my Windows boot (on the same computer) it works just fine, along with all my other devices. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have done the standard checks to ensure the problem is with your device:

- move computer closer to the router (if possible)
- disable ALL other devices connected to the network (except the router)
- restart the router
- try connecting via Ethernet cable (if possible)

I know they are frustratingly mundane but they are worth checking anyway to get a picture of where the problem starts (from personal experience, I have a laptop which can knockout all other devices on the network for example, and interference is occasionally a problem)

Please could you give details on:

- What you refer to when you say "doesn't work"; at what point in the process of connecting to the network does it fail? Can you see your home network in the list of networks, can you select it and get to the point of entering the wireless password (assuming it is secured), do you get a specific message telling you it cannot connect or does it appear connected to the network but you have no internet/network traffic?
- The wireless hardware you are using. I'm no expert but opening terminal (ctrl + alt + T) and typing `sudo lshw -C network` (then your password when prompted) should give you details of your network devices. Are you using an internal wireless card or a USB wifi dongle?
- What computer you are running 13.04 on (is it a laptop or PC)
- If you can, give details of the router you are communicating with (there can be issues with different versions of wireless interfaces 802.11b/g/n)